# AeroAdmin crashs in Wine under 64-bit Linux

Tags: 64-bit, remote

I am looking for a remote control software which runs in 64bit-linux and works without being in the same network. The only program (except of TeamViewer) I found is AeroAdmin.
According to its homepage [it runs under wine](https://www.aeroadmin.com/de/).
When I start it with wine it crashes (program error, a severe error occured).
`Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x293fe998 in 32-bit code (0x7e64c706).`

After that it seems to run (it shows its main window) but does not work properly. I suppose it only runs on 32 bit systems.

- Does anybody have a solution for that problem?
- Is there any free software except TeamViewer and AeroAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [DWService](https://www.dwservice.net/) pretty good. The free version has a 6 Mbps rate limit. It allows unattended login, file transfer, and remote file browsing.

Comment: Do you have experience what is better/worse in comparison between DWService <=> TeamViewer <=> AeroAdmin?

Comment: @MichaelHutter Teamviewer = expensive for always-on remote management. AeroAdmin = seems buggy on Linux, read through this question ;) . DWService = installing on Linux not for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

AeroAdmin Tech Support informed me:

> yes, you are correct. It works only in 32-bit version of the debian
> distribution.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, execute the `aeroadmin` command with parameter `d`:

> wine /[path_to_file]/aeroadmin.exe d

You can create a shortcut with the parameter `d` to make it easy to execute.

Comment: what is parameter "d" and why might it help? Please provide enough details that another user would be able to tell if the solution will be helpful.